# Should I store Image in to Cache that are already in my SQLite Database in android

Tags: android, image, caching

I'm developing an Android app and I need to store an Image in cache, but I have an Image as a byteArray in my SQLite Database. So if I store the Image in cache, will it increase the performance of Listview or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase your performance, why not use Picasso lib for image loading in your list view. Picasso does cache the image it loads, though you can switch if off if you dun want to cache it.

Check it out at:
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 0):

In your database, you should only store a reference/uri of the image, that you store on the device as a file using one of the Android storage options